# Understanding Soap with XML body

Tags: php, xml, laravel, soap, xsd

I have a WSDL that i am using, now i would like to understand how i can make the request...
If i `var_dump($client->__getTypes())` 
I get a list of arrays which is fine but i am looking at this element.

```
 0 => string 'struct CreateSession {
 SessionCreateRQ rq;
}'
```

This is the code i am using.

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<SessionCreateRQ></SessionCreateRQ>');
$xml->addChild('AccountNumber',env('MYFAREBOX_ACCOUNT_NUMBER_LIVE'));
$xml->addChild('Password',env('MYFAREBOX_PASSWORD_LIVE'));
$xml->addChild('Target',env('MYFARBOX_TARGET_LIVE'));
$xml->addChild('UserName',env('MYFAREBOX_USERNAME'));

$session = $this->tidyUp($xml->asXML());
$rq = new SoapVar($session,XSD_ANYXML);

$r =  $this->build()->CreateSession(array('rq' => $rq));
```

Any thoughts on where i am going wrong?